# How can I assign Rotate View Direction to SHIFT + mouse wheel instead of SHIFT + Numpad 4 or 6?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, mouse

Currently in Blender 2.93, probably since blender 2.7... there's no precise way of rotating blender viewport like displayed in the screenshots... except for the keys **Shift + Numpad 4** and **Shift + Numpad 6**

can anyone please help me out in adding a shortcut for this task, that should use **Shift + Scroll Wheel** ...?

I watched a video couple months back doing the same thing I need right now, but I cannot find that video now...

[VIDEO of rotating using Shift + Numpad 4/8](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18AlnCH3HilQqGQyJGdqhGeGlB6o-gGx6/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Thank You for your Time

Comment: You have to press to of them at once and scroll with the mouse wheel. (ctrl+alt, shift+alt ctrl+shift).

Answer (score 2):

Open the preferences with Edit > Preferences, go to the Keymap panel and type "View Roll" in the search bar while Name is selected.

Expand the two first entries under 3D View :

[image]

Click on Numpad 4 and scroll your wheel up, click on Numpad 6 and scroll your mouse down.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Thank you :)‎
‎
‎

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure exactly what you are asking, but more than likely the answer can be found in Preferences > Navigation > play with the settings in the Orbit & Pan and Zoom sections. Perhaps "Orbit around selection" relates to what you are looking for?

Comment: I've added a Video link...

Comment: Thanks again, for your time